# Загрузка изображения на сервер по ссылке

Tags: php, парсер, сервер

Решил попробовать написать свой парсер для сайта и столкнулся с небольшой проблемой. Ну, начну с того, что парсер работает, он отлично собирает информацию, но вопрос заключается в том, как загрузить изображение на сервер, имея лишь ссылку на изображение.

Например, у меня есть ссылка https://example.com/uploads/picture.png, как мне получить изображение по этой ссылке и загрузить его на сервер?

Вот мой код, если требуется:

```
//Выбор нужного сайта
$ParseURL = 'https://example.com';

//Ищу нужную информацию 

$ParseContent = file_get_contents($ParseURL);

$ParseObject = phpQuery::newDocument($ParseContent);
$ParseResultTitle = $ParseObject->find(".bw-title-wr .bw-title")->text();
$ParseResultAuthor = $ParseObject->find(".bw-book-card .bw-author")->text();

$ParseResultPoster = $ParseObject->find(".bw-img>img");

//Избавляюсь от лишних элементов в URL картинки

$DeleteSTR = array('<img src="', '"', '>');
$ReplaceSTR = array('', '', '');
$ResultSTR = str_replace('<img src="', '', $ParseResultPoster);
$FinalResultSTR = str_replace('">', '<br>', $ResultSTR);

//Вывод результата

echo "<br> Title <br>", $ParseResultTitle;
echo "<br> Autor <br>", $ParseResultAuthor;
echo "<br> Poster <br>", $FinalResultSTR;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого используйте функцию [`copy()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.copy.php).

Либо стандартное решение с помощью функций [`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php) + [`file_put_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-put-contents.php).

```
file_put_contents('filename.png', file_get_contents('image_link'));
```